# RadioButton // setUserData and getUserData don't work as expected

Tags: java, radio-button, user-data

I am working with `RadioButton`s and try to use the `setUserData` method in order to identify them later on. After educating myself on this topic, I've been thinking that I can `setUserData` using the `RadioButton` reference and `getUserData` using the `Toggle` reference later on, just as done in this [Oracle article](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/radio-button.htm) (Example 4-4).

Now, this hasn't been working out the way I wanted and led to a lot of frustration. I discovered, that I cannot get the same `userData` I have set using the `RadioButton` reference when applying `getUserData` on the `Toggle` reference that is returned after using `group.getSelectedToggle()`. Does anybody know why? Or how I can avoid this issue elegantly?

I tried to make my issue clear in my **SampleController.java** file, which you can find below. The `for loop` you'll see is the first idea I came up with, but is definitely not a proper solution...

My **Main.java:**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString() +
                    "\n" + e.getCause());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My **sample.fxml:**

```
<VBox id="VBox" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="application.SampleController">

    <Label text="Select a time, then press the button" />

    <fx:define>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="group" />
    </fx:define>

    <RadioButton id="rBtn1" text="Button 1" toggleGroup="$group" />
    <RadioButton id="rBtn2" text="Button 2" toggleGroup="$group" />
    <RadioButton id="rBtn3" text="Button 3" toggleGroup="$group" />

</VBox>
```

My **SampleController.java:**

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

    RadioButton rBtn1 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rBtn2 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rBtn3 = new RadioButton();

    @Override
    public void initialize (URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        rBtn1.setUserData("Button 1");
        rBtn2.setUserData("Button 2");
        rBtn3.setUserData("Button 3");

        System.out.println(rBtn1.getUserData()); // prints 'Button 1'

        System.out.println(group.getToggles().get(0).getUserData()); // prints 'null'

        List<Toggle> toggles = group.getToggles();
        int i = 1;
        for (Toggle t : toggles) {
            t.setUserData("Button " + i);
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(group.getToggles().get(0).getUserData()); // prints 'Button 1'

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use "fx:id" instead of "id" for the rBtn1... Which means that rBtn1 is not the same as the rBtn1 in your fxml file.

Changing:

```
<RadioButton id="rBtn1" text="Button 1" toggleGroup="$group" />
<RadioButton id="rBtn2" text="Button 2" toggleGroup="$group" />
<RadioButton id="rBtn3" text="Button 3" toggleGroup="$group" />
```

to:

```
<RadioButton fx:id="rBtn1" text="Button 1" toggleGroup="$group" />
<RadioButton fx:id="rBtn2" text="Button 2" toggleGroup="$group" />
<RadioButton fx:id="rBtn3" text="Button 3" toggleGroup="$group" />
```

Will fix your problem.

When doing this:

```
System.out.println(group.getToggles().get(0).getUserData()); // prints 'null'
```

You are referencing the rBtn1 from the fxml file, which you can reach by Node traversal from your group, which has a correct fx:id.

When you are doing:

```
t.setUserData("Button " + i);
```

and redoing:

```
System.out.println(group.getToggles().get(0).getUserData()); // prints 'null'
```

The value has been set through the group traversal and therefore returns the expected value.

```
rBtn1.setUserData("Button 1");
```

is just setting the local class variable rBtn1's UserData.

Comment: Damn, this is way to simple.. Now some other little issues I had observed but could solve with quick fixes are much clearer. Thanks a lot!